# Combining like minded entries in SQL

Tags: sql

What I would like to do is combine like minded sets into one clear entry.  Here is some example data:

```
Item    Warehouse   Quantity
Apple   Northeast   100
Apple   Midwest 2000
Apple   South   300
Orange  Northeast   400
Orange  Midwest 800
Orange  South   100
Orange  West    100
Strawberry  Northeast   550
Strawberry  Midwest 750
Strawberry  South   250
Strawberry  East    350
```

What I would like is for the SQL query to return the total quantity from all the warehouses.  The hopeful output would be something such as:

```
Item  Quantity
Apple 2400
Orange 1400
Strawberry 1900
```

Any help would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: Check out GRoup BY and Sum

Comment: `SELECT Item, SUM(Quantity)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Item, sum(Quantity) as TotalQuantity
from {tablename}
group by Item;
```